# Sorbet `srb init` fails with Kernel#exit due to conflict with yard gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yard, sorbet

We're starting to use Sorbet at work and `srb init` throws an error requiring [yard](https://github.com/lsegal/yard). Files still generated and seemed to work fine until `srb tc` started to produce errors like the following:

```
sorbet/rbi/todo.rbi:38: PG::Error was previously defined as a class https://srb.help/4012
    38 |module PG::Error; end
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    sorbet/rbi/hidden-definitions/hidden.rbi:121092: Previous definition
      121092 |class PG::Error
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Re-generating the hidden definitions with `bundle exec srb rbi hidden-definitions` produced the same error as `srb init`, and neither one fixes the problem. It seemed worthwhile to get to the bottom of the error in order to ensure our sorbet files are generating correctly.

With: Ruby 2.6.5, Rails 6.1.4.1, Sorbet 0.5.9115, Yard 0.9.26

Steps to reproduce:

```sh
gem install rails
rails new srb_yard_test
cd srb_yard_test
```

Add the following to the Gemfile

```
gem 'yard'
gem 'sorbet', :group => :development
gem 'sorbet-runtime'
```

```sh
bundle install
bundle exec srb init
```

Snippet from the `srb init` output:

```
Naming YARD::Handlers::Ruby::Legacy/Users/grahammelcher/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/yard-0.9.26/lib/yard/parser/ruby/legacy/irb/slex.rb:18: warning: already initialized constant IRB::SLex::DOUT
/Users/grahammelcher/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/irb/slex.rb:24: warning: previous definition of DOUT was here
/Users/grahammelcher/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/yard-0.9.26/lib/yard/parser/ruby/legacy/irb/slex.rb:19: warning: already initialized constant IRB::SLex::D_WARN
/Users/grahammelcher/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/irb/slex.rb:25: warning: previous definition of D_WARN was here
/Users/grahammelcher/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/yard-0.9.26/lib/yard/parser/ruby/legacy/irb/slex.rb:20: warning: already initialized constant IRB::SLex::D_DEBUG
/Users/grahammelcher/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/irb/slex.rb:26: warning: previous definition of D_DEBUG was here
/Users/grahammelcher/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/yard-0.9.26/lib/yard/parser/ruby/legacy/irb/slex.rb:21: warning: already initialized constant IRB::SLex::D_DETAIL
/Users/grahammelcher/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/irb/slex.rb:27: warning: previous definition of D_DETAIL was here
Naming YARD::Server::CommandsKernel#exit was called while requiring ruby source files
Traceback (most recent call last):
    61: from /Users/grahammelcher/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sorbet-0.5.9115/bin/srb-rbi:237:in `<main>'
    60: from /Users/grahammelcher/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sorbet-0.5.9115/bin/srb-rbi:196:in `main'
    59: from /Users/grahammelcher/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sorbet-0.5.9115/bin/srb-rbi:121:in `init'
    58: from /Users/grahammelcher/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sorbet-0.5.9115/bin/srb-rbi:232:in `block in make_step'
    57: from /Users/grahammelcher/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sorbet-0.5.9115/lib/hidden-definition-finder.rb:38:in `main'
    56: from /Users/grahammelcher/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sorbet-0.5.9115/lib/hidden-definition-finder.rb:44:in `main'
    55: from /Users/grahammelcher/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sorbet-0.5.9115/lib/hidden-definition-finder.rb:75:in `all_modules_and_aliases'
    54: from /Users/grahammelcher/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sorbet-0.5.9115/lib/hidden-definition-finder.rb:68:in `constant_cache'
    53: from /Users/grahammelcher/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sorbet-0.5.9115/lib/gem-generator-tracepoint/tracer.rb:40:in `new'
    52: from /Users/grahammelcher/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sorbet-0.5.9115/lib/gem-generator-tracepoint/tracer.rb:40:in `new'
    51: from /Users/grahammelcher/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sorbet-0.5.9115/lib/constant_cache.rb:70:in `initialize'
    50: from /Users/grahammelcher/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sorbet-0.5.9115/lib/constant_cache.rb:211:in `dfs_module'
    49: from /Users/grahammelcher/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sorbet-0.5.9115/lib/constant_cache.rb:211:in `each'
    48: from /Users/grahammelcher/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sorbet-0.5.9115/lib/constant_cache.rb:212:in `block in dfs_module'
    47: from /Users/grahammelcher/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sorbet-0.5.9115/lib/constant_cache.rb:211:in `dfs_module'
    46: from /Users/grahammelcher/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sorbet-0.5.9115/lib/constant_cache.rb:211:in `each'
    45: from /Users/grahammelcher/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sorbet-0.5.9115/lib/constant_cache.rb:212:in `block in dfs_module'
    44: from /Users/grahammelcher/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sorbet-0.5.9115/lib/constant_cache.rb:211:in `dfs_module'
    43: from /Users/grahammelcher/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sorbet-0.5.9115/lib/constant_cache.rb:211:in `each'
    42: from /Users/grahammelcher/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sorbet-0.5.9115/lib/constant_cache.rb:212:in `block in dfs_module'
    41: from /Users/grahammelcher/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sorbet-0.5.9115/lib/constant_cache.rb:145:in `dfs_module'
    40: from /Users/grahammelcher/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sorbet-0.5.9115/lib/constant_cache.rb:145:in `each'
    39: from /Users/grahammelcher/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sorbet-0.5.9115/lib/constant_cache.rb:157:in `block in dfs_module'
    38: from /Users/grahammelcher/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sorbet-0.5.9115/lib/real_stdlib.rb:77:in `real_const_get'
    37: from /Users/grahammelcher/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sorbet-0.5.9115/lib/real_stdlib.rb:77:in `call'
    36: from /Users/grahammelcher/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sorbet-0.5.9115/lib/real_stdlib.rb:77:in `const_get'
    35: from /Users/grahammelcher/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.2/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
    34: from /Users/grahammelcher/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.8.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    33: from /Users/grahammelcher/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.8.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    32: from /Users/grahammelcher/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.8.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    31: from /Users/grahammelcher/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.8.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    30: from /Users/grahammelcher/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.8.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
    29: from /Users/grahammelcher/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/yard-0.9.26/lib/yard/server/commands/frames_command.rb:2:in `<main>'
    28: from /Users/grahammelcher/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/yard-0.9.26/lib/yard/server/commands/frames_command.rb:3:in `<module:YARD>'
    27: from /Users/grahammelcher/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/yard-0.9.26/lib/yard/server/commands/frames_command.rb:4:in `<module:Server>'
    26: from /Users/grahammelcher/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/yard-0.9.26/lib/yard/server/commands/frames_command.rb:6:in `<module:Commands>'
    25: from /Users/grahammelcher/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.2/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
    24: from /Users/grahammelcher/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.8.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    23: from /Users/grahammelcher/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.8.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    22: from /Users/grahammelcher/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.8.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    21: from /Users/grahammelcher/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.8.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    20: from /Users/grahammelcher/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.8.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
    19: from /Users/grahammelcher/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/yard-0.9.26/lib/yard/server/commands/display_object_command.rb:2:in `<main>'
    18: from /Users/grahammelcher/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/yard-0.9.26/lib/yard/server/commands/display_object_command.rb:3:in `<module:YARD>'
    17: from /Users/grahammelcher/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/yard-0.9.26/lib/yard/server/commands/display_object_command.rb:4:in `<module:Server>'
    16: from /Users/grahammelcher/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/yard-0.9.26/lib/yard/server/commands/display_object_command.rb:6:in `<module:Commands>'
    15: from /Users/grahammelcher/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.2/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
    14: from /Users/grahammelcher/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.8.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    13: from /Users/grahammelcher/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.8.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    12: from /Users/grahammelcher/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.8.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    11: from /Users/grahammelcher/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.8.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    10: from /Users/grahammelcher/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.8.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
     9: from /Users/grahammelcher/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/yard-0.9.26/lib/yard/server/commands/library_command.rb:4:in `<main>'
     8: from /Users/grahammelcher/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/yard-0.9.26/lib/yard/server/commands/library_command.rb:5:in `<module:YARD>'
     7: from /Users/grahammelcher/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/yard-0.9.26/lib/yard/server/commands/library_command.rb:6:in `<module:Server>'
     6: from /Users/grahammelcher/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/yard-0.9.26/lib/yard/server/commands/library_command.rb:32:in `<module:Commands>'
     5: from /Users/grahammelcher/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/yard-0.9.26/lib/yard/server/commands/library_command.rb:34:in `<class:LibraryCommand>'
     4: from /Users/grahammelcher/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/fork_tracker.rb:8:in `fork'
     3: from /Users/grahammelcher/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/fork_tracker.rb:8:in `fork'
     2: from /Users/grahammelcher/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/fork_tracker.rb:10:in `block in fork'
     1: from /Users/grahammelcher/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/yard-0.9.26/lib/yard/server/commands/library_command.rb:34:in `block in <class:LibraryCommand>'
/Users/grahammelcher/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sorbet-0.5.9115/lib/require_everything.rb:94:in `block in patch_kernel': ExitCalledError (ExitCalledError)
```

It's a bit confusing because there's a missing newline after `YARD::Server::Commands`, so the error is actually:

`Kernel#exit was called while requiring ruby source files`

Interestingly, subsequent runs of `bundle exec srb init` or `bundle exec srb rbi hidden-definitions` fail at a slightly different place than the first run and generate slightly different sorbet files. Second run fails at `Yard::Tags` instead of `YARD::Server::Commands`. `bundle exec srb rbi hidden-definitions` fails at `Naming YARD::Templates`.

I've tried some of the suggestions from https://github.com/sorbet/sorbet/issues/975 e.g. using `require: false` on yard but same issue.

Open to work-arounds or suggestions on how to resolve. There's a [related issue](https://github.com/sorbet/sorbet/issues/1476) where a project called `exit` on load and broke `srb init` in the same way, and the response from the sorbet team was basically "your code is calling Kernel#exit, don't do that".

Planning to file an issue with Yard and/or Sorbet but it's unclear if they'll care to fix it, and I'm still unclear on what in the yard code is calling `#exit` on file load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution to this is to use [Tapioca](https://github.com/Shopify/tapioca) to generate your signatures, rather than Sorbet's built-in `rbi init`/RBI generator system. It's generally better and faster in my experience.